# Getting error Warning: Could not link libevent. Unlinking

Tags: tmux, libevent

Trying to install tmux on OSX but getting:

```
$ brew install tmux
Error: You must `brew link libevent' before tmux can
mdurrant@C02MH2DQFD58:~
$ brew link libevent
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21... 
Warning: Could not link libevent. Unlinking...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/include/event2
```

I can't use sudo with brew.

I'd tried installing libevent previously by compiling it locally and now I can't seem to get rid of the traces of it, though I went to where I had it and did `sudo make uninstall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was:

Install iterm2

```
brew install automake 

brew install pkg-config
rm configure
sh autogen.sh 
./configure 
make
make install
```

This helped (http://whiletruecode.com/post/installing-iterm2-and-tmux-osx) and I had an almost identical experience though the final step was not the broken link but to do the above